# What kind of heating lamp?

Tags: leopard-geckos

I keep my room at about 68 degrees all year round, i have a heating pad for my gecko but what type of lamp should i use? He never really comes out of his cage. He is an albino Tremper.

Comment: Are you able to post photos of your setup?

Answer (score 2):

Roughly three things are important when considering lighting:

1. Temperature
2. Day-night cycle
3. UV

All three of these can be provided by heat lamps. However, they can also be substituted by something else.

If your room temperature and heat mat provide sufficient heat for the Gecko, that's fine. Also, if the light in your room follows a day-night cycle already, you don't need to add that either.

Most heat lamps have some UV light in their spectrum to emulate sunlight. Animals need a bit of UV light to synthesize some specific nutrients. This is harder to substitute, but might be doable with food supplements, but I'm not sure about that.

So, to consider are whether the heating you provide now gets the tank to a sufficient temperature. If so, you could get a heat lamp with a low wattage (25W-ish), so it doesn't give too much heat, but does provide the light (daylight and UV) for the other things.